# why Buffer[String] can not inherit from Buffer[AnyRef]

Tags: scala

```
class Test1(buf:Buffer[AnyRef])
class Test2(buf:Buffer[String]) extends Test(buf)
```

Compiler error:

```
type mismatch; 
found : scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] 
required:  scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Any] 
Note: org.msgpack.type.Value <: Any, but trait Buffer is invariant in type A. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't add `AnyRef` to `Buffer[String]`:

```
val b: Buffer[AnyRef] = Buffer[String]()
b += new Object // ???
```

`Buffer[String]` can't be `Buffer[AnyRef]` because `Buffer[T]` is not covariant on type parameter `T`. It can't be declared covariant (`Buffer[+T]`) because there is usage of `T` in contravariant position (for instance in `+=` method).